# I want to convert a ttk.Combobox to a CTkComboBox, but it then it doesn't work

Tags: python, tkinter, combobox, ttk, customtkinter

First, I will show the original code which is

```
def apply_filter(filter):
    image = Image.open(file_path)
    width, height = int(image.width / 2), int(image.height / 2)
    image = image.resize((width, height), PIL.Image.LANCZOS)
    if filter == "Black and White":
        image = ImageOps.grayscale(image)
    elif filter == "Blur":
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)
    elif filter == "Sharpen":
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN)
    elif filter == "Smooth":
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.SMOOTH)
    elif filter == "Emboss":
        image = image.filter(ImageFilter.EMBOSS)
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)
    canvas.image = image
    canvas.create_image(0, 0, image=image, anchor="nw")


filter_combobox = ttk.Combobox(left_frame, 
                                values=["Black and White", "Blur",
                                        "Emboss", "Sharpen", "Smooth"])
filter_combobox.pack()


filter_combobox.bind("<<ComboboxSelected>>",
                    lambda event: apply_filter(filter_combobox.get()))
```

And I would to be a CTkComboBox through changing the second block to

```
filter_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(left_frame, 
                                values=["Black and White", "Blur",
                                        "Emboss", "Sharpen", "Smooth"])
```

It printed without issues, but the options(BLUR, SHARPEN,SMOOTH, EMBOSS) no longer work!

I installed all the required libraries, and the whole code run good before i convert this part to Customtkinter

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `command` parameter:

```py
filter_combobox = customtkinter.CTkComboBox(left_frame, 
                                values=["Black and White", "Blur",
                                        "Emboss", "Sharpen", "Smooth"],
                                command=apply_filter)
```

The command passes the selected value to the function specified.

Here's a [link](https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/widgets/combobox) to the `CTkComboBox` documentation.